# How to build libssh2 for arm64 bit support iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, git, arm64, libssh2

I am trying to make build for libssh2 to support arm64 with following steps as in this [link](https://github.com/x2on/libssh2-for-iOS).

First of all I am going on path where I have downloaded example code as in above [link](https://github.com/x2on/libssh2-for-iOS), then running script file in terminal "./build-all.sh libgcrypt" as shown in steps.

But it won't make file libssh.a and in log file shows error or message like in screen attached.

[image] .

**Problem**

It may require to Checkout the submodules: as in steps before make build.

**git submodule init**

**git submodule update**

But I don't know how and where to use above commands to check out sub module.
Please suggest me how can I checkout or correct me if I am on wrong track.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to build library with 
**libgcrypt**
https://github.com/x2on/libgcrypt-for-ios.git
Download this code and copy in source file you have downloaded from link of [LIBSSH2](https://github.com/x2on/libssh2-for-iOS). OR you can clone it too as suggested steps in above link.

Need to follow same steps with **openssl** too, if you want to build it with openssl.

Comment: can you please describe the steps ..Me too stuck with 17 errors of libssl

Comment: @Rakesh, oh k, one question, do you have any idea about agent forwarding?

Comment: Sorry dude ., no idea about it